# Visual Studio mixed projects debugging

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, clr

I have a solution primarily based on C# projects, but I will occasionally need to use libraries written in native c++. The way I have solved this is by having a native project that simply acts as a wrapper for a native library, in this case OpenCV (I know I could use EMGUCV directly in C#, but in my experience it has some bugs that I would like to avoid and this is more a proof of concept anyways). I then have a C++ CLR project that references the native wrapper, and finally a C# project referencing the C++ CLR project. 
Strictly speaking I could just reference OpenCV directly from the CLR project instead of having the native wrapper project, but I would like to organize it this way both to conform to how the rest of the solution is organized and because I might at some point want to have this structure for another reason.

The first problem with this approach is that I can't find a way for Visual Studio to automatically include the dll of the native wrapper in the final target directory. Referencing the native project from the CLR project works flawlessly and referencing the CLR project from the C# project is no problem, but when I build it won't run because the native dlls are not brought to the final target. I solved this by adding some post build actions to copy the native dll and pdb files. This works, and I'm able to run the code with no errors. However, I'm unable to debug the native project. I hit breakpoints in the C# project and CLR projects, but not the native project.

What I have tried:

- In the C# project properties I have enabled the native code debugging option.
- In the CLR project I have set debugging mode to mixed.
- In the native project I have tried both native only and mixed debugging mode
- In the C# project I have checked allow unsafe code
- In visual studio under tools->options->debugging->general I have tried checking and unchecking use native compatibility mode and suppress jit optimization on module load.
- I tried opening the native project in a separate visual studio instance to attach the debugger to the project running from the whole solution, but I was not allowed to do this as the solution debugger was already attached to that project. Someone suggested to do this, but didn't explain how this could be done.

Comment: The only obvious thing you missed is the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" checkbox.  Must be turned on for C++/CLI projects.  Also turn off "Just My Code" to be sure.  Verify that you can see the native DLL getting loaded in the Output window and look in the Debug > Windows > Modules window to verify that the debugger found the PDB files for it.

Comment: I enabled use managed compatibility mode in tools->options, there isn't one for each project specifically? I could find no mention of any native dll being loaded in the output or in the modules window. Not the OpenCV dlls and not mine. The code is definitely running though, as I'm outputing some result images that do show up.

Comment: Only the debug settings of the EXE project that you start are relevant.  Not seeing the DLL getting loaded is of course a sure sign of trouble.  Other than forgetting to enable unmanaged debugging there is no hint why this would not work.  Be sure to not swallow exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the C# project I referred to before was in itself a dll being called by another C# exe project. When I enabled native debugging for this project, everything worked as expected.